# Analytical Solution to a Eigenvalue-like Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my research, the stationary condition of my optimization problem is the following:

$\frac{1}{2} C_1 B C_2 = \lambda B$.

$C_1 \in R^{m \times m}$, $C_2 \in R^{n \times n}$, $B \in R^{m \times n}$.

Both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are Positive Definite Symmetric matrices.

$C_1, C_2$ are the constant matrices, and $\lambda$, $B$ are the variables.

So, is there any analytical solution of $B$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, $B = 0$ is always a solution for any $\lambda$.

For a fixed $\lambda$, we can rewrite this equation as
$$
\left(\frac 12 C_1\right) B + B \left(-\lambda C_2^{-1}\right) = 0
$$
This is now a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).  There exists a non-zero solution $B$ if and only if the matrices $\frac 12 C_1$ and $\lambda C_2^{-1}$ have a common eigenvalue.

It is clear, then, what the possibilities for $\lambda$ are.  I don't know if there's more that can be said.